# The shady puzzle that will keep you in the dark

Tags: mathematics, geometry

The image below is the horizontal cross section of a room. The bulb shows the position of the single light source.

When the light is switched on, one wall (marked in brown) remains completely in shadow.

[image]

Today’s puzzle is as follows: Design a room with straight walls in which there is a position for a single light source that leaves either part or all of every wall in shadow.

Clarification: A point is in shadow if there is no direct line from the light source to it.

Extra clarification: The straight wall sections need to join, so the cross-section of the room is a polygon. You can’t have a free-standing wall.

---

This puzzle is from Alex Bellos’ puzzle column in The Guardian.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this (6 walls)?

> [image]
>  The 3 tiny walls are entirely in shadow, the larger walls only partially.

I assume that the polygon is not allowed to self-intersect, as that would not be regarded as “a room”. Otherwise a solution of 5 exists.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution that I initially came up with:

> [image]
>
>  The walls of the room are blue and the light is at the red spot.